# ClassCastException when using String[]

Tags: java, arraylist, classcastexception

I am using ObjectMapper to convert a JSON String to a Map but I get ClassCastException when trying to retrieve a value:

```
Map<String,String[]> args = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
String[] array = args.get(paramName);
```

then doing

```
String x = array[0];
```

gives

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String
```

How can this be when I clearly specify String[] and not ArrayList, and when the second line doesn't cause any errors...

Comment: ArrayList is Java's implementation of a dynamic array (so therefore has an underlying `String[]` to store values) but I doubt that's what you're running into here.

Comment: The actual type is erased at runtime. I think yoru `objectMapper` returns a `Map<String,ArrayList<String>>`, not `Map<String,String[]>`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight shouldn't that launch the ClassCastException at the previous line (`String[] array = args.get(paramName);`)

Comment: @SJuan76 Not necessarily, because the info of the type parameters is not available at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap.class` is the only information available to `objectMapper` at runtime.

It doesn't know that you declared a `Map<String, String[]>` on the left-hand side, so it does what most JSON mappers would do: It assumes you want a 1:1 map-based representation of the JSON which results in a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

Just use

```
List<String> list = args.get(paramName);
String x = list.get(0);
```

instead of `String[] array` and `array[0]`.

Better yet, map your JSON into actual model classes, not a `HashMap`.

Comment: i cannot change the type of args on the first line: Map<String, String[]>.. then when doing List<String> list = args.get(param) i expectedly get 'cannot convert from String[] to List'... how can i reconcile this

Comment: If you `System.out.println(args)` right after `objectMapper.readValue(...)`, what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

The object mapper does not obey (in fact cannot) the parameterized type information you used. It only knows about the class you are passing in as an argument. You'd be much better off using the generic type.

What you are actually getting back is:

```
Map<Object, Object> args = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

I recommend changing your code to use something that for your arguments and then doing class casts and checking accordingly.

For example:

```
Map<Object, Object> args = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
Object value = args.get("foo");
String x;
if (value instanceof String[]) {
    String[] array = (String[])value;
    x = array[0];
} else if(value instanceof List) {
    List<Object> list = (List<Object>) value;
    x = String.valueOf(list.get(0));
} else {
    //error handling
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis is incorrect. The line that throws the `ClassCastException` is

```
String[] array = args.get(paramName);
```

and not the later array access. The reason for the error to occur at this line is, I believe, obvious: the map value simply **isn't** an array, but is in fact an `ArrayList`.